# Mac keyboard from the command line

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script, and am attempting to open a separate terminal window to run commands in. I was able to open a new terminal window with
`open -a Terminal .`, but is it possible to switch between windows from bash?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using AppleScript. Some related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794050/applescript-to-open-named-terminal-window and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047748/select-a-particular-tab-in-terminal-depending-upon-the-content-using-applescript

Answer (score 1):

You can run AppleScript scripts using command osascript.

Script for activating Terminal window:

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate
```

Or opening new Terminal window:

```
tell application "Terminal"  
  do script " "  
  activate  
end tell
```

Found here - https://superuser.com/questions/195633/applescript-to-open-a-new-terminal-window-in-current-space